# bash scripting: sourcing tcsh script

Tags: bash, tcsh

I need to source a tcsh script from my bash script. I have tried to do it like this:

```
tcsh -c "source ~/test.tcsh"
```

The problem with this command is that `$_` is empty inside of the sourced tcsh script. Any ways to deal with that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is similar to trying to parse a ruby script with python.  The potential pitfalls are numerous.

Comment: Why is that? Wouldn't it be the tcsh that is sourcing a tcsh script?

Answer (score 1):

The source command runs the script in the current shell. `tcsh -c "source ~/test.tcsh"` sources the file `test.tcsh` in the shell running the `source` command, which is an instance of `tcsh`, not the `bash` shell that runs `tcsh`. You aren't going to be able to execute a `tcsh` script in any way that affects the environment of the *current* bash shell. You could start a new `bash` shell that inherits from an instance of `tcsh` which was so modified, with something like

```
tcsh -c 'source ~/test.tcsh; bash'
```

but that may not be what you need. For instance,

```
tcsh -c 'source ~/test.tcsh; bash'
echo "OK, we're back"
```

will leave you in an interactive `bash` shell, but you won't see "OK, we're back" until after you exit that shell, which will cause `tcsh` to exit and return control to the original.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But there was nothing about influencing the current environment in my question. The main problem is: why is `$_` empty in the sourced script and if there is any way to make it not empty.

Comment: Since `source ./test.tcsh` is the first command executed by the `tcsh` process, there is no previous command for `$_` to be set to. Were you expecting it to be exported by `bash`?

Comment: By the way, `source` here is irrelevant; since you are starting a new `tcsh` process anyway, `tcsh ~/test.tcsh` does the same thing, unless you are running more code than you indicate in the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't actually matter if I call any command before source, i.e. `tcsh -c 'ps; source ~/test.tcsh'`, `$_` is always empty... What kind of sorcery is this?

Comment: Don't tell me I have to `spawn tcsh` to achieve this :/